# Ubuntu server skill test

Tags: server, testing

Is there a website that tests how proficient a person is in using or maintaining an ubuntu server?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this? https://github.com/trimstray/test-your-sysadmin-skills

Comment: Thanks for the information, i appreciate it.